# Regular expression not matching complete input

Tags: regex

Why is the regular expression ([£€$¥£]|USD|US\$)\s?(\d*.?\d+|\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(.\d+)?) not matching US$ 150,000.00

Regular expression 1 :

```sh
([£€$¥£]|USD|US\$)\s?
```

matches US$

Regular expression 2 :

```sh
 (\d*\.?\d+|\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?)
```

matches 150,000.00

Concatenation of two expressions

```sh
([£€$¥£]|USD|US\$)\s?(\d*\.?\d+|\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?)
```

does not match US$ 150,000.00

demo : https://regex101.com/r/fJJWqv/1

EDIT : The Regular expression 2 does not match 150,000.00 but shouldn't it match the comma too because of (,\d{3})* ?

Comment: I'd contract it a bit, use non-capturing groups for those parts we are not interested in and swap the alternatives in the second group: `(?:[£€$¥£]|US[D$])\s?(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?|\d*\.?\d+)`. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/4xgeYg/1).

Answer (score 0):

Your second claim is untrue. `(\d*\.?\d+|\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?)` does not match `150,000.00`. Rather, it matches `150` and `000.00`. Since only the former is prefixed with `US $`, only it matches the third regex.

The reason for this is that the alternation order you specified favors a shorter match. To fix it, you can switch the alternation order: change `(\d*\.?\d+|\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?)` to `(\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?|\d*\.?\d+)`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out ,I missed that.Updated the question.I was expecting it to match the comma

Comment: @user3580455 When you make my change, it does match the comma.

Answer (score 0):

In `150,000.00` using pattern `(\d*\.?\d+|\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?)` it will not match the comma because the 150 will be matched by `\d*\.?\d+` and none of the alternatives start with a comma.

It can because `\d*` means 0+ digits so that will match 150. Then the `\.?` is an optional dot so it continues to `\d+`.

Due to bracktracking the `\d*` can give up one match to match at least 1 digit from `\d+` and 150 will stay the match.

Then the next character is a `,` but non of the alternations start with a comma so the next character is tried and this time this pattern `\d*\.?\d+` can match the `000.00`.

One option to match your value (and if you only want the match you can omit the capturing groups) is you remove this part `\d*\.?\d+`

```
(?:[£€$¥£]|USD|US\$)\s?\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fAeBi8/1)